# i have to run my code 2 times before it actually works

Tags: c#, terminal, visual-studio-2022

I have this problem where when I make 1 singular change to my code in Visual Studio 2022 and try to run my code, it glitches the first time ( terminal just freezes so I close it ) and then I have to click the run button again ( or CTRL + F5 ) for it to work properly.

For example, I load up a completely new project, I see the `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` statement, I change the statement `Console.WriteLine("Hi all!");`, I run my code and the terminal freezes the first time so I have to close the terminal and rerun my code and then it works.
This happens every time I make a change to my code or just do anything at all in my code. The terminal consistently freezes the first time and only works the second time.

TL;DR every time I do anything at all in my code and try to run it, the terminal freezes and I have to rerun my code for it to work.

I asked my college professor and he said he didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Tried a reinstall of visual studio?

Comment: not yet, reinstalling is kind of a last resort since i really don't want to go through all of the steps again. also im a newbie to c# and programming in general so i would have to ask my college professor to guide me through everything again

Comment: If you wish not to reinstall Visual Studio, you can also try to Repair it. However, (to my knowledge) this does not guarantee that the issue will be solved. To Repair, close Visual Studio, open Visual Studio Installer, select your version of Visual Studio that you're having problems with, click on More, and Repair. (You'll need administrator privileges). If the issue is not solved, the reinstallation of Visual Studio will most likely eliminate the problem. Repairing and reinstalling Visual Studio will also remove user settings, profiles, etc.

Comment: will repairing visual studio 2022 also remove any user profiles etc?

Comment: Yes, repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio will also remove any user profiles. For more information, you can refer to the Microsoft Learn documentation that describes how to repair Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022. Note that I also know only the basics of Visual Studio, so I don't know everything about the IDE. However, theoretically this shouldn't delete the solutions or projects that you have, since they can be left anywhere.

Comment: please add screenshots of this issue to the question and describe in detail the steps that are triggering it

Comment: It seems that every time you run a piece of code, if you want to modify this piece of code, it will be interrupted when you run it again, and you must continue to run it again. It is possible that there is an error with Visual Studio's autosave function. You can try to hold down ctrl+s every time you modify the code to save it and run it again.